# Deploy C# .NET Webapplication on ubuntuu using mysql database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nginx, web-deployment

since long I try to host my web application on a linux ubuntu server.
How do I proceed, someone can send me a guide. I didn't find anything after a long search.

I have already taken the first step and uploaded my database to the server.
No clue whats next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a C# application on Linux OS you need to develop it on .NET Core which supports cross-platform development.

1. Check if your Linux server has `dotnet` installed with ([src](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#install-the-runtime))

> dotnet --list-runtimes

If not installed, install it with following.

> sudo apt-get update; 
> sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && 
> sudo apt-get update && 
> sudo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-6.0

2. Then follow a simple guide for a sample project on `asp.Net core` e.g. [this one](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Core-Sample-Web-Application.aspx)
3. Build your project and copy the files to your destination server path (e.g. from *C:\MyUser\MyFirstWeb\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1* to */home/MyFirstWeb/* in server or if you already develop in Linux no need for this step)
4. `ssh` to your server and run the application with `dotnet MyFirstWeb.dll` in its terminal